# Font with a particular style for the letter "x"

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'd like to find a font in which the letter "x" looks like the unicode character [U+1D4CD: MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL X](https://charbase.com/1d4cd-unicode-mathematical-script-small-x), that is,

in the style which you would write by hand with two curved vertical strokes, )(.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like the math font used by LaTex. Try [CMU Classical Serif Oblique](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern) or [Latin Modern Roman Italic](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman)

Comment: Thank you very much!  Indeed, this request came from mathematics writing: one uses this style for the letter "x" to distinguish it from the symbol "times".  I checked out the two fonts you suggested and indeed the "x" is exactly what I wanted, but they turn out to have another problem for mathematics writing: they are "italic"/"oblique" fonts and symbols like +, = display with a slant.

Comment: @anonymous The x style that you’re specifying **is** italic – it’s a handwritten script style. You’re not likely to find any regular, upright fonts whose normal letter x is italic and scripty while the rest is normal. The CMU family linked to above has an Upright Oblique version, which has the italic designs of letters, but without slanting. It sort of looks terrible, but that sort of thing may be the closest you’re going to get. But _why_ do you want this in a font?